# Bundle issues when publishing app

Tags: xcode, ios8

I made a custom keyboard for IOS 8, but when I try to archive it, i get the following error:

ITunes Store operation failed. No software with CFBundleIdentifier of "my project prefix" exists. Verify your bundle identifier is correct.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Simple fix -

You need to go on to iTunes Connect and create an app with the Bundle ID that you have created and set up through either Xcode or the Developer Center. Once that is set up it will then work (unless there are other problems with your app!)

Comment: same problem, I have created this app in iTunesConnect and still seeing the issue